# Restart footnote counter with apa6

Tags: footnotes, counters, apa6

I would like to reset the footnote counter to 1 after using some footnotes in the title page. I though the solution would be to simply `\setcounter{footnote}{0}` but it does not work. MWE below.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt]{apa6}
\title{Title}
\author{Author\footnote{Corresponding address}}
\affiliation{Workplace}
\abstract{Abstract}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\par Text here. \footnote{Want this footnote number to restart at 1 and increment as usual for the rest of the document.}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to set the footnote counter after `\maketitle` etc. Setting it to `0` in the document preamble (even before `\maketitle`) is useless, since `\maketitle` (better the setup of `apa6`) will increment it but it's not reset automatically after that.

```
\documentclass[man,12pt]{apa6}
\title{Title}
\author{Author\footnote{Corresponding address}}
\affiliation{Workplace}
\abstract{Abstract}
\setcounter{footnote}{0}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\par Text here. \setcounter{footnote}{0}
\footnote{Want this footnote number to restart at 1 and increment as usual for the rest of the document.}
\end{document}
```